# AngularJS Nested Scope/View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to access a `$scope` variable defined in the `$parent`'s, `$parent` scope?

E.g.:

```
var foo = $scope.$parent.$parent.foo; /* evaluates to undefined */
```

Is this possible, recommended, there a better alternative?

Comment: [Check out the rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) of angular. On the other hand, if you have the option to get away from this situation, I suggest you do it.

Comment: it *is* possible to do this,  but the larger question is, why do you need to? the more that you rely upon using `$parent`, the more spaghetti code you end up with.  nested controllers are generally something you should try to avoid whenever possible.  Imagine reading someone's code and trying to figure out where `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.aproperty` is actually defined.

Comment: i've inherited an AngularJS project. previous developer thought it'd be a bright idea. re-write may be in order in the future. for now it's "when in rome ... "

Comment: my recommendation in these cases is to start with converting to the ControllerAs Syntax, using a different name for each controller; i.e. `controllerA as ctrlA`, `controllerB as ctrlB`, etc..  Then you can begin to separate the nesting by referring to each property in terms of the controller that it belongs to, i.e. `ctrlA.property`, `ctrlB.property`;  you'll likely find a property or two with name collisions, but you'll be able to more easily identify what is going on with each property, and might find the nesting isn't even necessary.

Comment: they are using ControllerAs, but still referring to `$scope.$parent.$parent`? that doesn't make much sense at all

Comment: I've seen a lot of code where people use `controllerblah as vm` everywhere, and you have `vm.someproperty` all over the place, and even though it's not relying on `$scope`, it's still far from clear.

Comment: no, i was trying to use `$scope.$parent.$parent`, not knowing better ... going to utilize the `as ...` now. thanks for the dialog bud, helped ...

Comment: keep in mind, when you use the ControllerAs syntax, the controller becomes a *property* on `$scope`, and thus properties added to the controller can be referenced through `this` in the controller.  but what that means is, if you reference the `$scope.$parent`, it might actually be `$scope.$parent.someController.someProperty` that you are trying to reach.

Comment: i miss the days of writing raw javascript ...

Answer (score 1):

You should follow [**dot rule**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) in such cases that will allow you to access the parent scope without having `$parent` annotation.

If you look at [**`ng-controller`**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L232) API, you will find that the `scope: true` option which does mean New controller does create a scope which is prototypically inherited from the parent controller, that does allow access to object property which has been already declared in parent scope.

Basically that does follow [**prototypal inheritance.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
   <h1>my Controller Scope Here</h1>
   <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.data"/>
   <div ng-controller="innerController">
      {{myCtrl.data}}: {{innerCtrl}}
   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.myCtrl = {};
})

app.controller('innerController', function($scope){
    $scope.innerCtrl = 'inner Data';
})
```

Comment: `scope:true` or `abstract:true` ?

Comment: @culturalanomoly what do you mean by `abstract: true`..there is no such property exists in directive API..are you ok?

Comment: that's `angular ui-router`

Comment: @culturalanomoly could you looked at my update..by which you can overcome the use of `$parent`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83479/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-culturalanomoly).